# Difference between an allocator and a built in array in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation, allocator

I have lately been trying to create custom containers that are similar to some of the library containers (i.e vector, list). and while I was using an allocator to allocate dynamic memory I noticed that the idea behind allocators and built in arrays are the same. allocators reserve a certain amount of raw, unconstructed dynamic memory and return a pointer to the first free location in that pool of memory. and built in arrays pretty much do the same thing. so if we have an  std::allocator for strings called `alloc`
this code`alloc.allocate(7)` and this code `string* array = new string[7]` should have the same effect. and if we want to construct the raw memory we can call `std::allocator::construct` passing it the pointer returned from the `allocate` function, or we can have something like `array[0] = string("something")` to do the same thing. correct?
so what is there a difference between how an allocator work and how a built in array work?

Comment: "and built in arrays pretty much do the same thing." – NOPE NOPE NOPE NOPE. Wrong. "Built-in" (primitive) arrays are not pointers, they are nothing *like* pointers, and they don't allocate memory with dynamic storage duration.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: I *think* that you're misreading the question. He's pointing out that `new string[7]` could be written in terms of the allocator interface, and he's right.

Comment: I think my question was misunderstood, I was mainly asking about the standard library allocator provided in c++. and my main question was whether calling `std::allocator::allocate` have the same effect as `new T[]` or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that they're fundamentally related, but not in that way. `new string[7]` could indeed be decomposed into `allocate` and `construct` (with a few extra bits for EH and other details).

Separating them out in the allocator interface allows much more fine-grained control for containers so that they can, for example, have memory with non-constructed objects in them, which is often vital for correct performance guarantees or semantics.

Additionally, The allocator interface is, of course, an *interface* with many possible implementations, such as memory arenas or object pools, which `new string[7]` really doesn't offer.

Finally, `new T[]` is shit and don't ever use it. The allocator interface is designed to be used only by fairly experienced programmers in quite limited ways- as a component of a better library component. `new T[]` is a language feature that everybody can just use, with terrible results.

Comment: > "for example, have memory with non-constructed objects in them." isnt that what using `new T[]` does?

Comment: @user3769877: No, `new` creates objects after allocating memory for them. `allocator::allocate` just allocates memory; then you need to use `construct` to create objects. That's how, for example, `vector` can allocate space for more objects than it currently contains.

Answer (score 0):

An **array** is collinear container of slots for items in memory.  The array is a range.

An **allocator** is an *function object* (*or function*) that reserves memory.  The allocator can designate space from an array, stack, heap, or other areas of memory.  The allocator can also be used to allocate space outside of the memory area, such as a hard drive or other device (maybe a server, cloud, etc.)

The space allocated for an array is usually determined by the compiler during the build phase.

An allocator is used for dynamic (during run-time) allocation of objects.

Comment: so you're saying that the memory reserved by an allocator is not contiguous?

Comment: No, I did not say that.  An allocator may reserve contiguous space, it may not.  Depends on the *implementation* of the allocator.  Usually, an allocator is a function *you* write that allocates memory the way *you* want or from a source that isn't dynamic memory used by `operator new`.

Comment: Ok, I think my question was misunderstood, would you kindly look at my comment on the question, and maybe give me an answer in terms of that

Comment: You also mentioned that arrays size is known during compilation. Does that apply for all arrays,  including dynamically alocated ones? Since i know that a dynamically allocated array may not know its size until run-timr?